# NewtworkImageLoadException - I can't load image to my emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, http

I wrote this code recently but it doesn't get me the result!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;
import 'package:pics/src/widgets/image_list.dart';
import 'models/image_model.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return AppState();
  }
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  int counter = 0;
  List<ImageModel> images = [];

  void fetchImage() async {
    counter++;
    final Uri rep =
        Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/$counter');
    var response = await get(rep);
    var imageModel = ImageModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    setState(() {
      images.add(imageModel);
    });
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ImageList(images),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Lets see some images'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: fetchImage,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The terminal say this:

> The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image
> codec:         HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403,
> https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:117:9)
>
> Image provider: NetworkImage("https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
> scale: 1.0)   Image key:
> NetworkImage("https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952", scale: 1.0)

and this is image list class if you need to read it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/image_model.dart';

class ImageList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ImageModel> images;

  ImageList(this.images);

  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: images.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return Image.network(images[index].url);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and this is Image Model:

```
class ImageModel {
  late int id;
  late String title;
  late String url;

  ImageModel(this.id, this.title, this.url);

  ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    id = parsedJson['id'];
    title = parsedJson['title'];
    url = parsedJson['url'];
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include your `ImageModel`

Comment: i added my friend. you can check this out!

Comment: I would suggest please print url before "return Image.network(images[index].url);" this line and check url is correct or not and if possible please share here.

Comment: Model seems ok, based on error code, request is not authorized.

Comment: yep. do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @rezli take the url and try to open in normal browser if you are not able to access then you need to do changes in backend as frontend code looks like okay

Answer (score 0):

You can use web render, run with `--web-renderer html`

```
flutter run -d c --web-renderer html
```

`-d` to select device, where `c` is chrome